# Should I call close() on bind() or listen() error

Tags: sockets, bind, listen

Should I call `close()` when `bind()` or `listen()` error occurs?

Most socket program examples do not use `close()` on `bind()` or `listen()` error like below

```
if (listen(server, 5) == -1) {
    // Should I call close(server) here?
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Depending on language and operating system, exiting the program will automatically close and release all sockets. It's a good habit to do it explicitly anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do anything else with "server", then yes.

socket() creates an endpoint for communication and returns a file descriptor. close() closes a file descriptor, so that it no longer refers to any file and may be reused.